# How to get best nearest value of row in dataframe based on a row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

Dataset I have

```
Food Name          Protein  Calorie Carbohydrate    Calcium
Butter, salted     0.85     717       0.06          24.0
Butter, whipped    0.49     718       2.87          23.0
Butter oil         0.28     876       0.00          4.0
Cheese, blue       21.40    353       2.34          528.0
Cheese, brick      23.24    371       2.79          674.0
```

and a row...

```
Protein Calorie Carbohydrate    Calcium
56      2200    130             8
```

Here which row is best matched with the row ?

Comment: you need to give more examples of what you want to achieve with maybe an expected output as well

Comment: How do you define "best matched"?

Comment: nutrition of a food is best nearest with given nutrition row...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need:

```
#get diffrence of matched columns, convert to absolute
df3 = df1[df2.columns].sub(df2.iloc[0]).abs()

#compare by minimal values, count them by sum
s = df3.eq(df3.min()).sum(axis=1)

#filter rows with maximal count
df = df1[s.eq(s.max())]
print (df)
    Food Name  Protein  Calorie  Carbohydrate  Calcium
2  Butter oil     0.28      876           0.0      4.0
```

Comment: I think you need to add `.abs()` to the compare logic as the values could in principle be negative.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can use [**Cosine similarity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) for the distance between given vector compared to the given matrix. Finding abs is not a good way because data are not normalised.

```
    import numpy as np
    from numpy import dot
    from numpy.linalg import norm

    a = np.array([[0.85,717,0.06,24.0],[0.49,718,2.87,23.0],[0.28,876,0.00,4.0],[21.40,353,2.34,528.0],[23.24,371,2.79,674.0]])
    b = np.array([56,2200,130,8])
    cos_sim = dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))

    selected_row = np.argmin(cos_sim) + 1 
    print ("Distances:")
    print (cos_sim)
    print ("Selected_row: " + str(selected_row))
```

Comment: @H R shuvo can you please verify the answer and accept if this is what you are looking for. If not let us know how can we help you out?